# How to restart Ansible host machine on Linux?

Tags: ansible

I've installed Ansible host on my RHEL Linux machine.

I made some configurations changes and I want to restart it but I can't find how it's being done.

I used [this manual](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#installing-on-the-control-machine) for installation.

Checking running services I don't see an Ansible service.

How can I restart Ansible?

*NOTE: I installed Ansible from source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible is not a service, it is an executable program (actually a few executables) which is called, starts, and ends its execution.

There is no way to restart Ansible other than calling it again. The changes in configuration will be reflected on the next run.

Also: there is no "*Ansible host*" component. "Ansible control machine" is a general term for the machine you run Ansible executables on.

---

Similarly [Ansible-Pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull) is also not a service, but a script which is scheduled externally.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ps -ef|grep ansible
```

to double check that there is no ansible service or daemon.